# How can i plot graph and its root?

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I am using this code.

```
wn = 100;
aap = 0.2;
ome = 9;
Solve[{(2 x + 2) ((dco - wn aap x)^2 + 1) + 4*ome*x == 0}, {x}] 
Plot[{x /. %}, {dco, -40, 0}]
```

I am using this upper code and getting the right graph. But the Problem is that I do not want the result in this form as it is showing like this:
I want to calculate roots.

> {{x -> 0.0333333 (-10. + dco) + ((5.20833*10^-6 - 
>          9.0211*10^-6 I) (-548800. - 64000. dco - 
>          1600. dco^2))/(-6560. - 1371. dco - 60. dco^2 - 1. dco^3 + 
>         5.19615 Sqrt[
>          99259. + 143320. dco + 24722. dco^2 + 1160. dco^3 + 
>           19. dco^4])^(
>       1/3) - (0.00833333 + 0.0144338 I) (-6560. - 1371. dco - 
>          60. dco^2 - 1. dco^3 + 
>          5.19615 Sqrt[
>           99259. + 143320. dco + 24722. dco^2 + 1160. dco^3 + 
>            19. dco^4])^(1/3)}, {x -> 
>      0.0333333 (-10. + dco) + ((5.20833*10^-6 + 
>          9.0211*10^-6 I) (-548800. - 64000. dco - 
>          1600. dco^2))/(-6560. - 1371. dco - 60. dco^2 - 1. dco^3 + 
>         5.19615 Sqrt[
>          99259. + 143320. dco + 24722. dco^2 + 1160. dco^3 + 
>           19. dco^4])^(
>       1/3) - (0.00833333 - 0.0144338 I) (-6560. - 1371. dco - 
>          60. dco^2 - 1. dco^3 + 
>          5.19615 Sqrt[
>           99259. + 143320. dco + 24722. dco^2 + 1160. dco^3 + 
>            19. dco^4])^(1/3)}, {x -> 
>      0.0333333 (-10. + dco) - (
>       0.0000104167 (-548800. - 64000. dco - 1600. dco^2))/(-6560. - 
>         1371. dco - 60. dco^2 - 1. dco^3 + 
>         5.19615 Sqrt[
>          99259. + 143320. dco + 24722. dco^2 + 1160. dco^3 + 
>           19. dco^4])^(1/3) + 
>       0.0166667 (-6560. - 1371. dco - 60. dco^2 - 1. dco^3 + 
>          5.19615 Sqrt[
>           99259. + 143320. dco + 24722. dco^2 + 1160. dco^3 + 
>            19. dco^4])^(1/3)}}

I want my answer in interpolation form.
I think you can help me.

Comment: @vijay Okay, after deleting and inserting several spaces, I am confident that I was able to reproduce the code _that you actually used_. Please, always **copy** the code (in input form) from you notebook to your post. Otherwise, important information might be lost.

Comment: @vijay It is still unclear what you want because you attempt to solve a polynomial equation of order three. What you see is are the three general solution of which  one or more may be complex. The plotting routine returns nonreal input.

Comment: @gwr Sorry, now question is clear. i have edited it. i want to find out roots and plot it.

Comment: Have you tried `Reduce[{(2 x + 2) ((dco - wn aap x)^2 + 1) + 4*ome*x == 0}, {x}]`? You can convert the conditions to rules for plotting by using `ToRules`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
wn = 100;
aap = 1/5;
ome = 9;

sol = Solve[{(2 x + 2) ((dco - wn aap x)^2 + 1) + 4*ome*x == 0}, x] // 
  FullSimplify

(* {{x -> 1/30 (-10 + dco) + (343 + 
       dco (40 + dco))/(60 (-6560 - dco (1371 + dco (60 + dco)) + 
         3 √(297777 + 
             3 dco (143320 + dco (24722 + dco (1160 + 19 dco)))))^(1/3)) + 
    1/60 (-6560 - dco (1371 + dco (60 + dco)) + 
       3 √(297777 + 
           3 dco (143320 + dco (24722 + dco (1160 + 19 dco)))))^(1/3)}, {x -> 
   1/30 (-10 + 
       dco) - (I (-I + Sqrt[3]) (343 + dco (40 + dco)))/(120 (-6560 - 
         dco (1371 + dco (60 + dco)) + 
         3 √(297777 + 
             3 dco (143320 + dco (24722 + dco (1160 + 19 dco)))))^(1/3)) + 
    1/120 I (I + Sqrt[3]) (-6560 - dco (1371 + dco (60 + dco)) + 
       3 √(297777 + 
           3 dco (143320 + dco (24722 + dco (1160 + 19 dco)))))^(1/3)}, {x -> 
   1/30 (-10 + 
       dco) + (I (I + Sqrt[3]) (343 + dco (40 + dco)))/(120 (-6560 - 
         dco (1371 + dco (60 + dco)) + 
         3 √(297777 + 
             3 dco (143320 + dco (24722 + dco (1160 + 19 dco)))))^(1/3)) + 
    1/120 (-1 - I Sqrt[3]) (-6560 - dco (1371 + dco (60 + dco)) + 
       3 √(297777 + 
           3 dco (143320 + dco (24722 + dco (1160 + 19 dco)))))^(1/3)}} *)
```

If you use [`Evaluate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Evaluate.html) ([`Attributes`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Attributes.html) of [`Plot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html) include [`HoldAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldAll.html)) you will see that the curve is composed of  segments from each of the three roots. No single function can represent the curve since the curve is not single-valued for all values of `dco`.

```
Plot[Evaluate@(x /. sol), {dco, -40, 0},
 PlotStyle -> (Directive[Thick, ColorData[97][#]] & /@ {1, 3, 2}),
 PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, {0.5, 0.625}]]
```

[image]

If you want only real expressions, then the roots will be [`ConditionalExpression`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConditionalExpression.html)s and be expressed in the form of [`Root`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) objects.

```
(solr = Solve[{(2 x + 2) ((dco - wn aap x)^2 + 1) + 4*ome*x == 0}, x, 
    Reals] // Simplify) // Short[#, 5] &
```

[image]

```
Plot[Evaluate@(x /. solr), {dco, -40, 0},
 WorkingPrecision -> 15,
 MaxRecursion -> 10,
 PlotStyle -> (Directive[Thick, ColorData[97][#]] & /@ {1, 3, 2}),
 PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, {0.5, 0.625}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thankyou very much.